# How to get current maven goal version

Tags: java, maven, plugins, runtime, maven-plugin

In a maven plugin project if you use

```java
@Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}")
private MavenProject project;
```

Then you get the project that runs this plugin. How to get version of current Maven goal inside the maven goal itself, more specifically, this part of the project's pom.xml?

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.my.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>!! I want to get this !!</version>
      </plugin>
<plugins>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your mojo:

```
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${plugin}", readonly = true ) // Maven 3 only
private PluginDescriptor plugin;
```

Other available instances can be found at https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html#Supported_Annotations

Comment: Thanks will try as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

PluginDescriptor is only available for Maven 3, if you don't wanna be restricted by Maven version, you could try addding this

```
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${mojoExecution}", readonly = true )
private MojoExecution mojo;
```

And get the version with

```
mojo.getPlugin().getVersion()
```